# Can I install PHP 5.3/5.4?

Tags: 12.04, server, php, lamp, webserver

I'm moving my vBulletin boards to a new server and after going through the regular steps to install LAMP, it seems it has installed PHP 5.5 which vBulletin apparently cannot work with.

Can I install PHP 5.3 or 5.4 instead?

To be clear, I have removed PHP for the time being. I'm not asking about downgrading.

Comment: Have you tried it on 5.5? I can't see anything that suggests it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The [PHP 5.4 and 5.3 tarballs are available here](https://www.php.net/downloads.php).